# Why is get_group so slow in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file with 400.000 rows and 15 columns. I have to make multiple filter operations for each row. So, I thought to use pandas and groupby to try to improve the performance. Using groupby is fast but get_group seems slow.

```
import pandas as pd

filepath = 'data.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(filepath, sep=',', na_values=['', '-'], parse_dates=True)
groups = df.groupby(['Year', 'Team'])
team_matches = groups.get_group(('2014', 'Barcelona'))
```

The groupby is very fast. But the get_group as the number of columns used for grouping increases gets really slow. For the above example it takes 0.6s to get the group.

To clarify, for every row in my csv I have to create a number of statistics based on the previous rows. My csv has football data with columns like hometeam, awayteam, full_time score, odds for each outcome.

An example would be to find the average goals scored by the home team.

```
goal_avg = np.average(df[(df['HOMETEAM'] == hometeam) & (df['LEAGUE'] == league)]['HOME_GOALS'])
```

Comment: Groupby just defines if you like a description of the group, it doesn't perform any grouping as such. Is the data sorted initially?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using, `get_group()`, you should use filtering (like `df[(df.Year == '2014') & (df.Team == 'Barcelona')]`). This is extremely fast and performs the same operation. Here's a detailed comparison of the two.

```py
In [1]: df = DataFrame(dict(A = np.random.randint(0,1000,size=N),B=np.random.randint(0,1000,size=N),C=np.random.randn(N)))

In [2]: %time df.groupby(['A','B'])
CPU times: user 0 ns, sys: 804 µs, total: 804 µs
Wall time: 802 µs

In [3]: g = df.groupby(['A','B'])

In [4]: %time g.get_group((100,100))
CPU times: user 1.47 s, sys: 93.8 ms, total: 1.56 s
Wall time: 1.57 s
        A   B   C
325601  100 100 1.547365
837535  100 100 -0.058478

In [5]: %time df[(df.A == 100) & (df.B == 100)]
CPU times: user 12.6 ms, sys: 317 µs, total: 12.9 ms
Wall time: 21.3 ms
        A   B   C
325601  100 100 1.547365
837535  100 100 -0.058478
```

This is a speed up of more than 70x. Moreover, filtering is the right way to access rows by column value and not groupby!

Answer (score 0):

You would have to show data to prove this. `get_group` is quite fast. The first iteration DOES do some caching, but it is minimal (sorting of the data is irrelevant)

```
N = 1000000 

In [4]: df = DataFrame(dict(A = np.random.randint(0,1000,size=N),B=np.random.randint(0,1000,size=N),C=np.random.randn(N)))

In [5]: %timeit df.groupby(['A','B'])
10000 loops, best of 3: 84.2 µs per loop

In [6]: g = df.groupby(['A','B'])

In [7]: %timeit -n 1 g.get_group((100,100))
1 loops, best of 3: 2.86 ms per loop
```

Further, you should not repeatedly using `get_group`, instead use the cythonized functions, `apply`, or iteration, see docs [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#iterating-through-groups)

Comment: I have noticed the exact same thing that you mention about the first iteration. Basically, I am searching for the fastest way to filter items based on some columns.

Comment: not clear what  you are trying to do. pls update your question.

Comment: Get group is extremely slow, unlike @Jeff has said. Simply filtering the DataFrame by the value is much much faster!

Comment: When the data is big and group number is large, `get_group` is really slow and  filtering the DataFrame by the value is much more slow