# Apply on *staggered* groups of Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, scipy

I have a DataFrames of data in 3 axis, with a membership label that I use to group:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( [[0, 1, 2,  0], 
                    [-1, 0, 1, 0],
                    [-2, 0, 3, 1],
                    [1, 1, 3,  1],
                    [1, 0, 2,  2],
                    [1, 0, 3,  2],
                    [6, 2, 1,  5],
                    [-4, 3, 0, 5],
                    [1, 0, -1, 6],
                    [0, 0, 3,  6]], columns = ['x', 'y', 'z', 'member'])
```

My goal is a bit contrived: I wish to find the pairwise distance between points of each group against the next `n_skip` groups, ordered from smallest to largest. This `n_skip` is what I mean by staggered:

For instance, for `n_skip=2`, I wish to find the distances of:

- the rows with `member == 0` --> against `member == 1, 2`
- rows with `member == 1` --> against `member == 2, 5`
- rows with `member == 2` --> against `member == 5, 6`
- rows with `member == 5` --> against `member == 6`
- no calculations for `member == 6`.

Is there a performant way to do this without a nested for-loop? This is alluded to [in this question answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25308763/why-is-get-group-so-slow-in-pandas) Intuitively I'm not able to use the traditional `apply` to parallelize functions on Pandas DataFrames. What is a fast way to apply a function to a *staggered* set of groups?

---

**EDIT1**
**My solution (for one axis only):**

```
    ## Heading ### Organize by group membership
    groups = df.groupby('member')

    # Define constants
    max_member = 6
    n_skip = 2
    start_row = 0
    matrix = np.zeros((df.shape[0], df.shape[0]))

    # Iterate for each group
    for i in range(max_member):

        try:
            pts_curr = groups.get_group(i)

        except KeyError:
            continue

        # Save end row index 
        end_row = start_row + pts_curr.shape[0]    

        # Save start col index
        start_col = end_row
        
        # Grab the destination group nodes
        for j in range(i+1, int(np.min([i+n_skip+1, max_member]))):

            try:
                pts_clr_next = groups.get_group(j)

            except KeyError:
                continue

            # Save end col index
            end_col = start_col + pts_clr_next.shape[0]

            # Calculate cdist
            z_sq = cdist(pts_curr[['z']], pts_next[['z']])

            # Save results in matrix at right positions
            matrix[start_row:end_row, start_col:end_col] = z_sq
            
            # update col index
            start_col = end_col

        # update row index
        start_row = end_row
```

Comment: Do the `member` groups always have the same number of rows?

Comment: No, unfortunately they do not. It was for convenience that I made the contrived example have the same number of memberships per group.

Comment: How large is your data? Maybe a cross merge will do.

Comment: It is not terribly large. In practice I am building a graph, where the ```matrix``` above is used to compute the adjacency matrix. My graphs have ~ 4000 nodes; but I have many such separate graphs (~1000 graphs). However, I'm trying to shave any ```ms``` of time. Previously my experience with cross merge has been that it is quite slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cross merge on 4K rows is not too bad (yielding about 16M rows). Let's try cross merge and query:

```
n = 2
# dummy key
df['dummy'] = 1
# this is the member group number
df['rank'] = df['member'].rank(method='dense')

# cross merge and filter
new_df = (df.merge(df, on='dummy')
            .query('rank_x<rank_y<=rank_x+@n')
         )

# euclidean distance
dist = (new_df[['x_x','y_x','z_x']].sub(new_df[['x_y','y_y','z_y']].values)**2).sum(1)**.5

# output dataframe with member label
pd.DataFrame({'member1':new_df['member_x'], 'member2':new_df['member_y'],
              'dist':dist})
```

Output:

```
    member1  member2      dist
2         0        1  2.449490
3         0        1  1.414214
4         0        2  1.414214
5         0        2  1.732051
12        0        1  2.236068
13        0        1  3.000000
14        0        2  2.236068
15        0        2  2.828427
24        1        2  3.162278
25        1        2  3.000000
26        1        5  8.485281
27        1        5  4.690416
34        1        2  1.414214
35        1        2  1.000000
36        1        5  5.477226
37        1        5  6.164414
46        2        5  5.477226
47        2        5  6.164414
48        2        6  3.000000
49        2        6  1.414214
56        2        5  5.744563
57        2        5  6.557439
58        2        6  4.000000
59        2        6  1.000000
68        5        6  5.744563
69        5        6  6.633250
78        5        6  5.916080
79        5        6  5.830952
```

---

**Option 2**: A loop might not be too bad if you have large dataframe:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

ret = []
for i in set(df['rank']):
    this_group = df['rank']==i
    other_groups = df['rank'].between(i,i+n, inclusive=False)
    t = df.loc[this_group,['x','y','z']].values
    o = df.loc[other_groups,['x','y','z']].values
    ret.append(cdist(t,o).ravel())

dist = np.concatenate(ret)
```

Comment: ```df.query('rank_x<rank_y<=rank_x+@n')``` is really nifty. I learned something new today, thank you.